# Why does Visual Studio Code say an error called "This app can't run on your PC" when I run it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before this problem happened, VS Code was working fine. Now, when I run VS Code, after a few seconds, it gives a system error "This app can't run on your PC". What do I do to stop VS Code from giving those messages so I can continue programming?

Comment: Does this help? https://appuals.com/fix-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-error-message-on-windows-10/

Comment: I also just started getting the error above from an executable compiled via VS Enterprise in a CI job-runner.  When I compile it locally, it runs great.